# Using factory arguments in replacement of properties

Tags: java, spring

My current project defines Spring beans using properties configured in a properties file (a classic `PropertyResolver`).

Example

```
<bean id="timestampService" class="org.acme.rfc3161.TimestampServiceImpl">
  <property name="url" value="${serverUrl:https://.....}" />
  <property name="username" value="${username}" />
  <property name="password" value="${password}" />
  <property name="someOtherBean">
    <bean >...
    </bean>
</bean>
```

Okay, this basically defines a singleton service which is configured centrally.

However, my new implementation requires multiple services, belonging to different accounts, to be instantiated. Of course not via `@Autowired`, but by the [`getBean(String,Object...)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html#getBean-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Object...-) method. I am basically creating a factory service that upon `url`, `username` and `password` (in the simplified example version) returns a running RFC3161 client in contrast to a singleton client.

Example call

```
TimestampService srv = (TimestampService) beanFactory.getBean("timestampService",serverUrl,username,password);
```

I would now like to understand how to map those parameters into the XML. I currently can't edit the `TimestampServiceImpl` by `org.acme` because I don't have the possibility to recompile and re-release it.

So my question is how do I bind a constructor argument / factory argument to a property in Spring 4.3? I know how to write XML to bind a static value or a property to a Java constructor argument of a bean, but not how to bind a value that comes from the `BeanFactory`'s caller to a property of the target bean. So that the Spring XML definition contains a partial set of the fields which will be completed upon call to the factory.

What I can currently do is to manually instantiate the object.

```
TimestampServiceImpl ret = new TimestampServiceImpl();
ret.setUrl(url);
ret.setUsername(username);
ret.setPassowrd(password);

ret.setAdditionalSpringBean(beanFactory.get("anotherBean"));

ret.afterPropertiesSet();

return ret;
```